# Сортировка текстовых данных на Python

Tags: python, сортировка, текст

Есть сейчас маленький скрипт, который выполняет команды и записывает лог выполнения в текстовый файл. 
Собственно нужно отсортировать эти данные из текстового по определенным ключам. 
К примеру не нужен весь мусор из файла , а нужны только определенные строки `Interface` , `ChassisID`, `SysName`, `MgmtIP`.
Как сделать так , чтобы записывались только уникальные содержания данных строк + записывались последовательно.

вот какой лог пишется в файлы:

---

```
 Local chassis:

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Chassis:     
  ChassisID:    mac 18:db:f2:3b:ba:29
  SysName:      alex-Latitude-E5570
  SysDescr:     Ubuntu 17.04 Linux 4.10.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 14:36:05 UTC 2017 i686
  TTL:          120
  MgmtIP:       10.22.1.217
  MgmtIP:       fe80::9648:fbb:be4f:930d
  Capability:   Bridge, off
  Capability:   Router, off
  Capability:   Wlan, on
  Capability:   Station, off
```

и

---

```
LLDP neighbors:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Interface:    enp0s31f6, via: LLDP, RID: 15, Time: 0 day, 00:00:38
    Chassis:  


    ChassisID:    mac 00:04:9f:ef:06:06
    SysName:      OpenIL
    SysDescr:     OpenIL 2017.12 Linux 4.9.35-ipipe #1 SMP Wed Jan 17 18:04:41 CET 2018 armv7l
    TTL:          120
    MgmtIP:       192.168.15.1
    MgmtIP:       fe80::204:9fff:feef:808
    Capability:   Bridge, off
    Capability:   Router, off
    Capability:   Wlan, off
    Capability:   Station, on
  Port:        
    PortID:       mac 00:04:9f:ef:08:08
    PortDescr:    eth2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Interface:    enp0s31f6, via: LLDP, RID: 16, Time: 0 day, 00:00:11
  Chassis:     
    ChassisID:    mac 48:4d:7e:f4:45:d0
    SysName:      alex-OptiPlex-7050
    SysDescr:     Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS Linux 4.10.0-28-generic #32~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 20 10:19:48 UTC 2017 x86_64
    TTL:          120
    MgmtIP:       172.15.0.2
    MgmtIP:       fe80::cb59:dfef:1cfc:d599
    Capability:   Bridge, off
    Capability:   Router, off
    Capability:   Wlan, off
    Capability:   Station, on
  Port:        
    PortID:       mac 48:4d:7e:f4:45:d0
    PortDescr:    enp0s31f6
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score -1):

```
ks = ('Interface' , 'ChassisID', 'SysName', 'MgmtIP', )
al = [line for line in open('log.txt') if any(line.lstrip().startswith(k) for k in ks)]
result = sorted(set(al), key=al.index)
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно сделать с использованием регулярных выражений:

```
import re
regex = 'Interface|ChassisID|SysName|MgmtIP'
log = open('log.txt').readlines()
matches = list(filter(lambda line: re.search(regex, line), log))
result = sorted(set(matches), key=matches.index)
```

Comment: Всем спасибо , упоролся и решился свой вопрос банальным 
os.popen ("grep"). И последовательно грепаю по меткам и дозаписываю в отдельный файл)